# Typescript is not accepting MUI-base componentType props for a component used within another custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to customize `InputUnstyled` from `MUI-base`. While there are no issues during runtime, Typescript shows an error when I try to access the `maxLength` attribute within `componentProps` for my customInput, made using InputUnstyled.

Can someone explain me how to solve this?
Here are the typescript errors I get:

> Property 'maxLength' does not exist on type 'SlotComponentProps<"input", InputUnstyledComponentsPropsOverrides, { slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ... 270 more ...; focused: boolean; }>'.

> Property 'maxLength' does not exist on type '(ownerState: { slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; color?: string | undefined; translate?: "yes" | "no" | undefined; hidden?: boolean | undefined; ... 267 more ...; focused: boolean; }) => Partial<...> & InputUnstyledComponentsPropsOverrides'.ts(2339)

And here's the code itself:
[image: CustomInput]

[image: Calling CustomInput]

Comment: The screenshot is nice to show the TS error in the IDE, but you should first paste the code as _text_ in the question. See [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the input @ghybs . I'm new to using stack overflow so I didn't know what was right or wrong while posting a question till now. I'll use your advice for my further questions.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if this is the right methodology, I've at least found a working solution in this case. I've created a new variable, `tempInput` and used a type alias to associate the variable with the `InputHTMLAttributes`. Here's the updated code:

```
function BaseInput(props: CustomInputProps) {
    let tempInput = props.componentsProps
        ?.input as InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
    if ((props.type === "tel" || props.type === "number") && tempInput?.maxLength ) {
        let value = props.value as string;
        if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(value[value.length - 1]))
            props = {
                ...props,
                value: value.slice(0, value.length - 1),
            };
        if (value.length > tempInput?.maxLength) {
            props = {
                ...props,
                value: value.slice(0, tempInput?.maxLength),
            };
        }
    }
    return <InputUnstyled components={{ Input: CustomInput }} {...props} />;
}
```

Comment: It is totally fine answering your own question! ;-)